# How do I manage multiple nested for-loops without using multiple variables?

Tags: c++, c, coding-style, loops

If I have code that looks like this:

```
int i;
void functionA (){
    for (i=0; i<10; i++){
        functionB();
    }
}
void functionB (){
    for (i=0; i<20; i++){
        doSomething();
    }
}
```

It seems like using the same variable `i` to iterate through the two for-loops would overlap and cause errors.

I've always just used a second variable instead of `i` to iterate through `functionB()`, but that gets hard to manage.
Is there an easier way to do this, like maybe making a variable private to one for-loop?  How do I do that?

Comment: "maybe making a variable private to one for-loop?" - yes, it's called a local loop variable, just declare it in the loop itself `for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)`. It's local to the loop block, and it goes out of scope when the loop ends; you can reuse the name all you like.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> It seems like using the same variable 'i' to iterate through the two for-loops would overlap and cause errors.

Indeed, it would. Well, not "errors", so much as unexpected behavior. The code you have is syntactically fine; no C or C++ compiler that I know of would raise any warnings, much less errors. However, if you [run it](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(fontScale:14,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:2,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:2,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:2,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:2),source:%27%23include+%3Cstdio.h%3E%0A%0Aint+i%3B%0Avoid+functionB+()%7B%0A++++for+(i%3D0%3B+i%3C20%3B+i%2B%2B)%7B%0A++++++++printf(%22%25d%5Cn%22,+i)%3B%0A++++%7D%0A%7D%0Avoid+functionA+()%7B%0A++++for+(i%3D0%3B+i%3C10%3B+i%2B%2B)%7B%0A++++++++functionB()%3B%0A++++%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Aint+main()%0A%7B%0A++++functionA()%3B%0A%7D%0A%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:26.17310195605413,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:gsnapshot,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%270%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%271%27,trim:%271%27),fontScale:14,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-O2+-xc+-Wall+-Wextra%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27x86-64+gcc+(trunk)+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B%27,t:%270%27)),k:29.687837724054827,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:1,editor:1,fontScale:14,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%231+with+x86-64+gcc+(trunk)%27,t:%270%27)),k:44.13906031989104,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4), you'll see that it merely loops through 20 times (`i` = 0 to 19).

Why? Because the `i` variable is a global variable, shared across both `functionA` and `functionB`. `functionA` initializes `i` to 0, then immediately (first iteration of the loop) calls `functionB`. `functionB` resets `i` back to 0 and then loops through 20 times before returning. Upon return to `functionA`, `i` has the value 19. That is not less than 10, so the check in the `for` loop's ending condition inside of `functionA` fails and the loop exits.

The behavior is correct and predicable, but unexpected, assuming that you were intending the loop in `functionA` to run through 10 times.

This is why shared state should be avoided whenever possible: it makes the behavior of a program more difficult to reason about.

> Is there an easier way to do this, like maybe making a variable private to one for-loop?

Yes, that is precisely what you should do. In fact, *always* prefer to reduce the scope of a variable whenever possible. What you have now is a *global* variable. Making a local variable (one that is local to each function) would be preferable, e.g.:

```c
void functionA (){
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<10; i++){
        functionB();
    }
}
void functionB (){
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<20; i++){
        doSomething();
    }
}
```

But even better is to actually scope the index variable to the `for` loop itself. That can be done by declaring the variable within the loop statements:

```c
void functionA (){
    for (int i=0; i<10; i++){
        functionB();
    }
}
void functionB (){
    for (int i=0; i<20; i++){
        doSomething();
    }
}
```

*Personally*, I like to write the increment statement as `++i`, since that's a better reflection of what is actually happening. As a bonus, it may, with certain types of objects, in certain languages, be more efficient. But in C and/or with an `int`, both forms result in identical object code. I just prefer the pre-increment.

Comment: In C, `++i` and `i++` do have different behavior, though it may not be observable in this code, and most optimizing compilers may output the same machine code (for this situation). But in general, `++i` returns the incremented value and `i++` returns the value from before the increment. `int a=0; int b=0; printf("%d, %d; ", ++a, b++); printf("%d, %d\n", a, b);` will print `1, 0; 1, 1`.